# Why is game over screen lagging?

Tags: android, lag

I have done a game in Android Studio with the goal of avoiding falling objects.
Generally the app is running good, but for some reason when i get to the game over screen and press an `edittext` to add highscore the game experience a lot of stutter and lag (with the keyboard und keypresses).

I have already called `finish()` (which can be seen in "FishView") on my main activity so I don't understand how it can be so slow on the game over screen, as it shouldn't have to worry about anything but the game over screen once it's there and the game over screen is very simple.

I'm having a hard time locating where the problem comes from, hence why I'm asking for help here.

Here is some code that I hope is sufficent for locating the problem:

MainActivity (deals with `animation`, level increase, spawn objects and interaction between objects and rules)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GarbageListener {

    //global variable of FishView
    private FishView gameView;

    //handle animation task
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    //global variable of screen
    private RelativeLayout screen;

    //time before level update
    private int levelChangeTime = 3; //initialize small garbage in X seconds
    private int spawnBossGarbage = 25; //initialize big garbage in X seconds
    private int spawnHeart = 40; //initialize heart in X seconds

    //pause variables
    private Button pauseButton;
    private boolean pauseFlag = false;

    //left and right button
    private Button leftButton;
    private Button rightButton;

    //List of small garbage on screen
    private final List<SmallGarbage> smallGarbages = new ArrayList<>();
    //List of big garbage on screen
    private List<BigGarbage> bigGarbages = new ArrayList<>();
    //List of heart on screen
    private List<LifePoint> lifePoints = new ArrayList<>();

    //create timer for animation and level increase
    private Timer mainTimer;

    //create timer fro holding left or right
    private Timer movingLeft;
    private Timer movingRight;
    private final boolean buttonIsPressed = false; //so players can't hold both buttons down
    private final int holdMovementPeriod = 9;

    //keep track of song
    public static Intent themeSong;
    //keep track of how far we are in the song, serviceStop() deletes everything in service ThemeSong so variable must be saved elsewhere
    public static int lengthOfSong = 0;
    public static boolean backButtonPressed = false; //check if backButton was pressed in service ThemeSong oonDestroy() since that's the last thing that is run


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        themeSong=new Intent(this, ThemeSong.class);
        startService(themeSong); //OR stopService(svc);

        leftButton = findViewById(R.id.leftArrow);
        rightButton = findViewById(R.id.rightArrow);

        screen = findViewById(R.id.gameScreen);
        gameView = new FishView(this);
        screen.addView(gameView);

        pauseButton = findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        mainTimer = new Timer();
        createNewAnimationTask();
        createNewLevelTask();

        //create listeners fo holding left or right button
        findViewById(R.id.leftArrow).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    holdLeft();
                    rightButton.setEnabled(false);}
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    rightButton.setEnabled(true);
                    if (movingLeft!=null){
                    movingLeft.cancel();
                    }}
                return false;}
        });

        findViewById(R.id.rightArrow).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    holdRight();
                    leftButton.setEnabled(false);}
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    leftButton.setEnabled(true);
                    if (movingRight!=null){
                    movingRight.cancel();}}
                return false;}
        });
    }

    public void moveLeft(@SuppressWarnings("unused") View v){
        if (buttonIsPressed){return;}
        gameView.setLeftPressed(true);
        gameView.leftFishAnimation();//before running the animations we first set which fish animations to run (left or right)
        gameView.invalidate();
    }

    public void moveRight(@SuppressWarnings("unused") View view) {
        if (buttonIsPressed){return;}
        gameView.setRightPressed(true);
        gameView.rightFishAnimation();
        gameView.invalidate();
    }

    public void pauseGame(View v){
        String resume = "Resume";
        String pause = "Pause";
        if (!pauseFlag){
            stopService(themeSong); //turn of music
            pauseFlag = true;
            pauseButton.setText(resume);
            pauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonred);

            //disable animation and level tasks
            mainTimer.cancel();
            //disable all falling garbage on screen
            for (SmallGarbage smallGarbage : smallGarbages) {smallGarbage.disableGarbageTimer();}
            for (BigGarbage bigGarbage : bigGarbages) {bigGarbage.disableGarbageTimer();}
            for (LifePoint lifePoint : lifePoints) {lifePoint.disableGarbageTimer();}
            //disable buttons
            leftButton.setEnabled(false);
            rightButton.setEnabled(false);

        }
        else{
            startService(themeSong); //start music
            pauseFlag=false;
            pauseButton.setText(pause);
            leftButton.setEnabled(true);
            rightButton.setEnabled(true);
            pauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbuttonblue);
            //resume falling garbage
            for (SmallGarbage smallGarbage : smallGarbages) {smallGarbage.startFallingGarbage();}
            for (BigGarbage bigGarbage : bigGarbages) {bigGarbage.startFallingGarbage();}
            for (LifePoint lifePoint : lifePoints) {lifePoint.startFallingGarbage();}
            //resume animation and level increase
            mainTimer = new Timer();
            createNewAnimationTask();
            createNewLevelTask();
        }

    }

    private void createNewAnimationTask(){
        TimerTask newAnimationTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //here we set the animation
                        int selectedFish = gameView.getSelectedFish();
                        selectedFish ++;
                        if (selectedFish==2){
                            selectedFish = 0;}

                        gameView.setSelectedFish(selectedFish);

                        //update screen
                        gameView.invalidate();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        long animationPeriod = 600;
        mainTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(newAnimationTask, 0, animationPeriod);
    }

    private void createNewLevelTask(){
        TimerTask levelCountDown = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                levelChangeTime--;
                spawnBossGarbage--;
                spawnHeart--;
                if (levelChangeTime==0 || spawnBossGarbage == 0 || spawnHeart == 0){
                    //move task that updates the UI onto the main thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //this tells the program to run this on the UI(aka main) thread, we could also call on new Thread if wanted to start new thread
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (levelChangeTime==0){generateNewGarbage("smallGarbage");}
                            if (spawnBossGarbage==0){generateNewGarbage("bigGarbage");}
                            if (spawnHeart==0){generateNewGarbage("lifePoint");}// when this is added we can't lose life?
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        mainTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(levelCountDown,0,1000);
    }


    private void holdLeft(){
        movingLeft = new Timer();
        final View v = new View(this); //create view so moveLeft() can called
        TimerTask holdLeftTask = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                moveLeft(v);
            }
                });
        }};
        movingLeft.scheduleAtFixedRate(holdLeftTask,0,holdMovementPeriod);
    }

    private void holdRight(){
        movingRight = new Timer();
        final View v = new View(this);
        TimerTask holdRightTask = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        moveRight(v);

                    }
                });
            }};
        movingRight.scheduleAtFixedRate(holdRightTask,0,holdMovementPeriod);
    }

    private void generateNewGarbage(String garbage){
        switch (garbage){
            case "bigGarbage":
                spawnBossGarbage = 40; //time to next spawn
                BigGarbage newBigGarbage = new BigGarbage(MainActivity.this);
                newBigGarbage.setListener(MainActivity.this);
                bigGarbages.add(newBigGarbage);
                screen.addView(newBigGarbage);
                break;
            case "smallGarbage":
                levelChangeTime = new Random().nextInt(20)+3; //set seconds between 3 and 20 at random
                //this create SmallGarbage and initialize its task
                SmallGarbage newGarbage = new SmallGarbage(MainActivity.this);
                newGarbage.setListener(MainActivity.this); // set listener for garbage
                smallGarbages.add(newGarbage);
                screen.addView(newGarbage);
                break;
            case "lifePoint":
                spawnHeart=30; //time to next spawn
                //this create SmallGarbage and initialize its task
                LifePoint newLifePoint = new LifePoint(MainActivity.this);
                newLifePoint.setListener(MainActivity.this); // set listener for garbage
                lifePoints.add(newLifePoint);
                screen.addView(newLifePoint);
                break;
        }
    }

    //here starts the GarbageListener
    @Override
    public void handleAvoidedGarbage(String avoidedGarbage) {
        gameView.avoidedGarbage(avoidedGarbage);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleHitPlayer(int x, int y, String garbageType) {
        return gameView.hitWasteChecker(x,y, garbageType);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleLoseLife() {
        gameView.loseLife();
    }


    //empty lives on screen, once they have landed or hit player
    @Override
    public void emptyLifePointList(){
        lifePoints.clear();
        lifePoints = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //empty big garbage on screen, once they have landed or hit player
    @Override
    public void emptyBigGarbageList(){
        bigGarbages.clear();
        bigGarbages = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //saving and setting length of played song
    public static int getLengthOfSong() {
        return lengthOfSong;
    }

    public static void setLengthOfSong(int lengthOfSong) {
        MainActivity.lengthOfSong = lengthOfSong;
    }

    //onStop runs AFTER onBackPressed(), so lengthOfSong must be reset there
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        backButtonPressed = true;
    }

    public static boolean isBackButtonPressed() {
        return backButtonPressed;
    }

    public static void setBackButtonPressed(boolean backButtonPressed) {
        MainActivity.backButtonPressed = backButtonPressed;
    }

    //this runs whenever the app is closed
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        //stop music
        stopService(themeSong);
        setLengthOfSong(0);

        //pause game, this will also reset sound upon start
        final View v = new View(this);
        pauseFlag = false;
        pauseGame(v);
    }

}
```

FishView (deals with creating the player, rules and HANDELING the starting the game over screen)

```
public class FishView extends View {

    private final Bitmap[] fish = new Bitmap[3];
    private final Bitmap gameBackground;
    private final Bitmap[] lifePoints = new Bitmap[2];

    private int selectedFish;

    private final Paint scorePaint = new Paint();
    private int score, fishLives;

    private static final int fishY = 1200;
    private int fishX = 400;
    private int speedX = 0;

    private boolean leftPressed = false;
    private boolean rightPressed = false;

    public FishView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        //set background
        gameBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.underwater);

        //set default/start fish animations
        leftFishAnimation();

        //set selected fish animation to default start on 0
        selectedFish = 0;

        //set life points
        lifePoints[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.lifepoint);
        lifePoints[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.deadlife);

        //set score
        scorePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        scorePaint.setTextSize(80);
       // scorePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD)); //??
        scorePaint.setAntiAlias(true); //(graphic improvement) this removes the staircase effect aka make smoother
        scorePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        score = 0;

        //set fish lives
        fishLives = 3;

    }

    //in a View, the onDraw method is called whenever:
    //the view is initially drawn or whenever invalidate() is called on the view
    //in our case we call on the constructor which initially the View
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //should maybe be canvas.getWidth() here
        int canvasWidth=getWidth();

        //set game boundaries
        int minFishX = 0; //should not be able to go of screen (to the left)
        int maxFishX = canvasWidth-fish[0].getWidth(); //furthers you can go to the right (to the right)

        //check boundaries
        if (fishX < minFishX) {
            fishX = minFishX;
        }
        if (fishX > maxFishX) {
            fishX = maxFishX;
        }

        //set position dependent on speed
        fishX += speedX;

        //draw background
        canvas.drawBitmap(gameBackground, 0, 0, null);

        //this draws the bitmap we decoded from the image
        if (leftPressed){
            speedX -= 15;
        }
        else if (rightPressed){
            speedX += 15;
        }

        if (speedX != 0){
        while (speedX != 0){
            if (leftPressed){
                fishX -= 1;
                speedX += 1;
                canvas.drawBitmap(fish[selectedFish],fishX,fishY,null);
                invalidate();

            }
            else if (rightPressed){
                fishX += 1;
                speedX -= 1;
                canvas.drawBitmap(fish[selectedFish],fishX,fishY,null);
                invalidate();
            }
        }}
        else{ //if nothing happens when we stay here
            canvas.drawBitmap(fish[selectedFish],fishX,fishY, null);
        }

        leftPressed=false;
        rightPressed=false;

        //draw score
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + score, 20 , 90, scorePaint);

        //draw life points and life point we have lost
        for (int lives = 0; lives < 3 ; lives++) {
            int lifeX = 650 + 140*lives;
            int lifeY = 10;

            if (lives < fishLives){
                canvas.drawBitmap(lifePoints[1],lifeX,lifeY,null);
            }
            else{
                canvas.drawBitmap(lifePoints[0],lifeX,lifeY,null);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean hitWasteChecker(int x, int y, String garbageType){
         switch (garbageType){
             //define hit boxes
             //first check is how far above, second how much underneath, third how much to the left, and fourth how much to the right
            case "smallGarbage":
                return  fishY <= y + 80  && fishY + fish[selectedFish].getHeight() >= y + 75 && fishX <= x + 75 && x + 20 <= (fishX + fish[selectedFish].getWidth());
            case "bigGarbage":
                return  fishY <= y + 170  && fishY + fish[selectedFish].getHeight() >= y + 75 && fishX <= x + 180 && x + 20 <= (fishX + fish[selectedFish].getWidth());
             case "lifePoint":
                 if (fishY <= y + 25  && fishY + fish[selectedFish].getHeight() >= y + 60 && fishX <= x + 110 && x + 35 <= (fishX + fish[selectedFish].getWidth())){
                     if (fishLives<3){fishLives++;
                     return true;} //if not full life gain a life
                     if (fishLives==3){score+=40; //if already full life then gain 40 points
                     return true;}}
                 return false;
            default:
                return false;
        }}


    public void loseLife(){
        fishLives--;
        if (fishLives<=0){
            //stop theme song from playing
            getContext().stopService(MainActivity.themeSong);

            //through these lines a new Activity can be created from a View
            Intent gameOverIntent = new Intent(getContext(), GameOverActivity.class);
            gameOverIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); //not possible to go back from game over screen
            gameOverIntent.putExtra("final score", score); // send data to game over activity
            getContext().startActivity(gameOverIntent);
            ((MainActivity) getContext()).overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            ((MainActivity) getContext()).finish(); //TIMERS is till running

        }
    }

    public void leftFishAnimation(){
        fish[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.leftfish1);
        fish[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.leftfish2);

    }

    public void rightFishAnimation(){
        fish[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.rightfish1);
        fish[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.rightfish2);
    }

    public void setLeftPressed(boolean leftPressed) {
        this.leftPressed = leftPressed;
    }

    public void setRightPressed(boolean rightPressed) {
        this.rightPressed = rightPressed;
    }

    public int getSelectedFish() {
        return selectedFish;
    }

    public void setSelectedFish(int selectedFish) {
        this.selectedFish = selectedFish;
    }

    public void avoidedGarbage(String avoidedGarbage){
        switch (avoidedGarbage){
            case "smallGarbage":
                score += 10;
                break;
            case "bigGarbage":
                score += 25;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

GameOver: (display the game over screen)

```
public class GameOverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //create instance of database
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private EditText usernameInput;
    private int score;
    private MediaPlayer gameOverSound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);
        score = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getInt("final score");
        usernameInput = findViewById(R.id.addUsername);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        //easier way of doing it
        gameOverSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gameoversound);
        gameOverSound.setVolume(0.2f,0.2f);
        gameOverSound.start();

        String yourFinalScore = "Your final score: " + score;
        TextView finalScore = findViewById(R.id.finalScore);
        finalScore.setText(yourFinalScore);

    }

    public void restartGame(View v){
        Intent restartIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        restartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); //so we can't go back to game over
        startActivity(restartIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out); //transition between activities
        finish(); //end this activity, MainActivity is already ended so can't only call on finish here to go back
    }

    public void backToStartMenu(View view) {
        Intent startMenuIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(startMenuIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        finish(); //end this activity
    }

    public void addHighscore(View view) {
        String writtenUsername = usernameInput.getText().toString();
        if (!writtenUsername.equals("") && score != 0){
            //insert writtenUsername and score into database
            boolean insertedData = db.insertData(writtenUsername, score);
            if (insertedData){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Highscore was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent startMenuIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(startMenuIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();}
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Highscore couldn't be added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    //this runs whenever the app is closed, mobile arrow is pressed or we switch activity
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        gameOverSound.stop();
        gameOverSound.release(); //solve error: if run twice the app will close because we cant release it twice
    }

    //if pressed mobile back button go back to start menu
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        View v = new View(this);
        backToStartMenu(v);
    }
}
```

What I find weird about this problem is that the MainActivity, with the player `animation` and all the falling view objects, runs fine. However, something as small as the game over screen is lagging. This leaves me to believe that I somehow don't quit my Activities as I should which leads to the main thread not being able to handel it. Anyways thank you for your time! :)

Update:
I checked it and it seems to be some real problem with the transition from MainActivity to GameOver. Using Android help -> find-action -> profiler, 
I was able to see that the memory useage was about 110 MB while in MainActivity and as soon as I got to the game over screen it went all the way up to 400 MB. But still I'm not able to locate why it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was the sharp background image that I was using in my GameOver screen, apparently it was too much for the game too handle. So if you have any similar problem try changing the images and backgrounds on the screen.